# How to create or write text file in servlet?

Tags: java, file

i have tried this code. I didn't create any file. I am doing this in netbeans where server is glassfish v2
public void create_file(String file_name)
    {
         FileWriter file_stream;
    BufferedWriter out_stream;

```
    try
    {
        file_stream= new FileWriter(file_name);
        this.out_stream = new BufferedWriter(file_stream);

    }
    catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any


     }

}
```

Comment: How is it related to servlets?

Comment: I am downloading a webpage using URL class and want to store it in text file in the server. Then i want to parse information. If any better way to do it let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're passing in a relative filename - and chances are the working directory isn't what you expect it to be. I suggest you use an absolute filename, or find out an appropriate directory to create the file relative to.

It would also help if you didn't swallow exceptions - if there's something going wrong, the exception is trying to tell you about it, but you're ignoring it completely.

Comment: How can i specify the path in servlet? Any example. Are there any permission issues?

Comment: You can specify it in the servlet configuration. As for whether there are any permission issues - that will depend on your environment. At the moment we can't tell, because you're swallowing the exception.

Comment: if my text file "test.txt" stored in a package name mypackage; what would the path of this file.

Comment: You're trying to *write* a file to the file system - packages are irrelevant at that point. They're for resources/classes to *read*. If you want to write it to the location where test.txt *would* be, it will depend entirely on your deployment scenario - but I really wouldn't recommend writing files into a deployment area, as they'll be overwritten when you next deploy.

Comment: I am very thankful to you. A brief of my work:
I am downloading a web page using URL class and want to store it in temporary text file . Then i want to parse information from that text file and store it to database. That's why i need a temporary text file. getabsolutepath() works ok. But i want to create a file on my own choice giving the file path. But i do not know how to specify the path. I don't care if the file overwritten on next deploy.  
If any better way to do it let me know.

Comment: If you only want a temporary text file, use System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"). However, I wonder whether you really need the text file at all... why don't you parse it in memory?

Comment: "parse it in memory"... how can I do it? Take the whole text into String or there are better ways...

Comment: It depends on how you've got the data to start with - but basically you can create a MemoryInputStream if you've got a byte array or a StringReader if you've got a string. That way you're basically where you would be if you opened a file.